# Will Google crawl a news/RSS aggregator site?

Tags: googlebot, aggregators

I know how to code. I know how to set up a news/RSS aggregator site. But I don't know if Google will crawl it. Will Google crawl such a site?

The site will have a listing of all the aggregated news with the title, a short snippet of the news, and an image (not all will have an image) of the original news article.

When a user clicks the article the user will get redirected to the source.

Something like drudgereport. I haven't seen a drudgereport link when I search so I can't tell. (Maybe because it has something to do with my location I don't know.)

Anyway any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google will crawl the page. Unfortunately for most news stories you'll never have a chance of showing up, because the article's you link to will be ranked higher. If you Google "Drudge Report", it should be the first result - So you know it's being crawled and indexed. Even if you Google "CONDOLEEZZA RICE STAKES STAGE AT CONVENTION", you should get a result that is a sub-page on the same domain.

The problem is that the content on the page is so thin, and it's almost all outgoing links. Generally Google doesn't like it when a landing page just directs users to another website, they'd rather send the user directly to that website.

With the snippets that you add, that might make the content a bit thicker, but at the same time it will all be considered duplicate content because the originating sites will have it published first.

Comment: "If you Google "Drudge Report", it should be the first result  - So you know it's being crawled and indexed" you do have a point haha. I'm just amazed of the stats that drudge displays (033,755,500 PAST 24 HOURS) (900,910,156 PAST 31 DAYS) (11,789,455,190 PAST YEAR) I would assume majority of that was from robots but when you look at his quantcast stats it still shows the same similar amount of visits. I'm wondering if its `direct` or `search` traffic. Anyway thanks for the tips!